# Assigning e-mails to accounts using nginx smtp proxy

Tags: nginx, smtp, proxy, authentication

I want to use nginx as SMTP proxy for SMTP authentication. However, is it possible to pair somehow smtp login with email which was sent using this login? Like adding additional header containing login which goes through the proxy etc, so the SMTP server knows which account was used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your use case.

In theory, nginx would just be passing the connection through to a backend server, in which case, I would assume the FROM field would contain the information you need.

If not, then there is some info in the mail headers that usually provides what you are looking for, e.g.:

```
Received: from some.node.tld (unknown [xx.xx.xx.xx])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (Client did not present a certificate)
    (Authenticated sender: USER.NAME@DOMAIN.TLD)
    by MAIL.DOMAIN.TLD (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 8828AC0FA5
    for <DESTINATION.USER@DOMAIN.TLD>; Fri,  1 May 201x 17:44:46 +0200 (CEST)
```

I am also not complete sure why you have nginx in the path - is there something specific you were trying to achieve?